# What's the simplest way to add a local image to a xamarin iOS app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#Local_Images) explains the *preferred* way of adding a local image to a xamarin forms iOS app (an image catalog).

I infer that there is... another way. A simpler way? My image is just a placeholder for some dynamic content I'll add later. What's the simplest brain-dead way of putting a local image in a xamarin iOS project?

Comment: You can always still just add images directly to the Resources folder if you don't want to use the asset catalog. You just need to add an image for each resolution/scale factor to it. For example, if you added an image to Resources MyImage@2x.png and MyImage@3x.png it will pick the appropriate image based on the scale factor and the device's screen size.

Comment: And that's all? No manifest entries or anything?

Comment: Yeah as long as the images on iOS aren't for your app icon/launch screen images, which those should definitely be handled by creating an asset catalog.

Comment: That's great. You don't feel like copying that into an answer, since the docs are so quiet on the question?

Comment: Will do as soon as I get to a computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always still just add images directly to the Resources folder. You just need to add an image for each resolution/scale factor to it. For example, if you added an image to Resources `MyImage@2x.png` and `MyImage@3x.png` it will pick the appropriate image based on the scale factor and the device's screen size.

However, on iOS, any of your app icon/launch screen images should definitely be handled by creating an asset catalog.